# How do I add time to a timestamp?

Tags: java, timestamp, addition

I need to add 14 minutes and 59 seconds to an unknown time in an array. How do I do this? This is what I have so far:

```
Date duration = df.parse("0000-00-00 00:14:59");

arrayOpportunity[2] = arrayOpportunity[2] + duration;
```

The time is not being changed.  Thanks!

I have done my research. I cant paste the entire code I have.  But mainly I didnt want to make you read it all.  Just looking for a simple answer of how to add two timestamps.

Comment: What type is the object in `arrayOpportunity[2]`?

Comment: It's a string.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply...first time using this site.

Comment: It probably is. You have to convert the string to an appropriate type, like `Date` and then add the time on that object.

Answer (score 10):

If you are talking about a `java.sql.Timestamp`, it has a method called [setTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#setTime%28long%29). `java.util.Date` has a `setTime` method as well for that sort of thing.

You could something like this:

```
static final Long duration = ((14 * 60) + 59) * 1000;

oldTimestamp.setTime(oldTimestamp.getTime() + duration);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add time in millis then you can just add

```
  (((14 * 60) + 59) * 1000) <-- Mili second value of 14 m and 59 sec
```

Comment: Thanks! I am much closer now.  This is where I am at:

  System.out.println(arrayOpportunity[2]);
  
  arrayOpportunity[2] += (((14 * 60) + 59) * 1000);

  System.out.println(arrayOpportunity[2]);

OUTPUT:

2012-11-15 04:00:00
2012-11-15 04:00:00899000

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add times, I suggest using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

The class [LocalTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) lets you add durations like this:

```
LocalTime timeSum = time.plusMinutes(14).plusSeconds(59);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the appropriate number of milliseconds using [`#getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime%28%29) and [`#setTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#setTime%28long%29):

```
timeStamp.setTime(timeStamp.getTime() + (((14 * 60) + 59)* 1000));
```

Comment: Just be careful, this doesn't factor DST and even the leap seconds we just had.

Answer (score 1):

`arrayOpportunity[2] = arrayOpportunity[2] + 14*60*1000 + 59*1000;`

The Date object you have may work, but it doesn't really represent 14 minutes and 59 seconds, it just represents a particular time in calendar (eg. 14 minutes 59 after the epoch start which is 1st January 1970 00:14:59).