# JSP/JAVA- Add 8 hours to time retrieve from database and display it without saving to database

Tags: java, jsp

Now, my database store transaction record and save in the transaction date and time but now I want to display it out by adding 8 hours but not be save in to the database. How can I make it?..

I'm thinking just make the changes to the jsp.

currently, the code to retrieve the time is

```
 <td align=right><%= tradePosition[i].getDate()!=null? tradePosition[i].getDate() :"" %></td>
```

Comment: You are looking for something like: tradePosition[i].getDate().addHours(8) - it just depends on what .getDate() returns. Is it Java class? Or your own custom class? Or some custom string?

Comment: the getDate declare in bean just get and set the Date function in order to get and retrieve data since i declare variable as private.

public Timestamp getDate() {
  return date;
 }

Answer (score 0):

According to your clarification:

```
<%
    Timestamp time = null;
    if (tradePosition[i].getDate() != null) {
        time = new Timestamp(tradePosition[i].getDate().getTime() + 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    } 
%>
<td align=right><%= time != null ? time : "" %></td>
```

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051298/how-do-i-add-time-to-a-timestamp).

This is the Timestamp class [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

Take care that this approach may have some issues with leap times and timezones, as pointed in the question, but it is generally good enough for non-critical use cases. If this is important to handle properly, I'd advise keeping some proper Date variable instead of Timestamp (or maybe keeping it in addition to the Timestamp in the class as a `@transient`).

Comment: it is not work....the time still display out the database time...not adding the 8 hours...

Comment: Ah, sorry - I thought setTime would return the timestamp itself after editing. Sleep is needed, as I've written in one of the edits :) Let me fix this.

Comment: system error...

or is it related to my broker coding problem...because the current function is select the date to date then filter the people make transaction on that period thn display it out by adding 8 hours...but not to stored in database

Comment: What error do you get? Maybe you need to include Timestamp in  the imports of the JSP page. Essentially, displaying the updated value in JSP is right for your scenario, since it makes no change in actual stored values. Also - I tweaked the code a bit; try using the updated code + correct import - and if still there is an error, please show it.

Comment: `<%
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(tradePosition[i].getDate());
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    
%>
 <td align=right><%= tradePosition[i].getDate()!=null? cal.getTime() :"" %></td>`

i success with this

Comment: Nice! Calendar will perform the correct addition, as well :) BTW, maybe worth checking if you can just format the `cal` with the timezone? Can save DST issues (if relevant - dunno if you have those).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your time addition should be done in a Servlet redirecting to the JSP.

```
if (tradePosition[i].getDate() != null) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

  cal.setTime(tradePosition[i].getDate());
  cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 8);

  request.setAttribute("displayDate", cal.getTime());
}
```

The JSP would then just display the date using JSP EL as

```
<td align=right>${displayDate}</td>
```

Notice how you no longer need the clumsy `null` check with EL.

---

If you're working with a `Timestamp`, use its *milliseconds* to set the initial time.

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(tradePosition[i].getDate().getTime());
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
```

Comment: in my broker is 

'bean.setDate(rs.getTimestamp("tp_date"));'

to set the date from the rs which to filter data and the jsp get to retrieve....but i nid to display the time by adding 8 hours coz currently the GMT is 0 now nid display in GMT 8